Risposta inserita per errore due volte / Answer inserted twice by mistake
Ho inserito per sbaglio la risposta a questa domanda due volte.
Ho provveduto a cancellarla ma mi compare come deleted answer. 
Sarebbe possibile da parte di un moderatore cancellare del tutto la risposta in modo che non compaia?
English version:
I accidentally inserted an answer to this question twice.
I proceeded to delete it but it shows up as deleted answer.
Could it be possible for a moderator to completely delete the answer so it won't show up anymore?

Non vedo il modo di rimuoverla del tutto.

Grazie comunque!

Questo è già accaduto in precedenza, vedi questa risposta. Penso che neanche i moderatori possano cancellarla del tutto.

La prossima volta starò più attento, mi dispiace.

I remembered just now that we should provide a translation to English of the post. Could you do it? (Per favore, lascia anche la versione in italiano).

Provided English translation

Thanks, @abarisone!

I don't think it is possible to permanently delete answers so that they cannot be recovered even by a moderator. I think that the current system makes sense. One of the reasons is preserving contributions permanently, so that they can be restored in case the community finds them useful. Another is that it adds accountability to moderators actions: all users with a sufficiently high reputation can see that a moderator deleted an answer, and judge their action.
Note that once you write an answer it is permanently licensed to Stack Exchange under a CC license, so even you as the author cannot prevent them from republishing it.
What you can do is editing the answer and replacing it with a short, informative text such as [Duplicated answer, removed].
(In this case, I don't know if you have done it already because I can't see your deleted answer --- not enough rep.)
